# How to pass thymeleaf String variable to javascript parameters?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Hi i'm junior programmer. Finally, i found a way to pass a time-leaf variable to Javascript function parameter. But I don't know how to do it when there are several String variables. How to pass multiple String variables in Javascript function? 
I attach the source below :)

```
function loadDetailView(no,type){
  ...
}

<tbody id="docsTr">
     <tr th:if="${size} == '0'">
    <td colspan=7>No data!</td>
    </tr>
     <tr th:unless="${size} == '0'" th:each="docs : ${list}" 
       **th:onclick="|loadDetailView(${docs.no},${docs.type})|"** (500 error!)
```

> *** docs.type is String and docs.no is Integer

```
        <td th:text="${docs.board_no}">1</td>
        <td th:text="${docs.name}">Brian Willson</td>
        <td th:text="${docs.emp_rank}">Manager</td>
        <td th:text="${docs.reg_date}">2019-07-16</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

error : Only variable expressions returning numbers or booleans ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly put String variables in `th:onclick` attributes anymore.  Instead, you put them in `data-*` attributes and reference those in your `onclick` functions.  In your case it would look something like this (**notice that it's no longer `th:onclick` it's just an `onclick` now**):

```
<tr th:unless="${size} == '0'"
    th:each="docs : ${list}" 
    th:data-docsNo="${docs.no}"
    th:data-docsType="${docs.type}"
    onclick="loadDetailView(this.getAttribute('data-docsNo'),this.getAttribute('docsType'))"
```